# What does it mean: "Assuming a matrix | Use a list of lists instead"?

Tags: matrix

I have entered a matrix by `Insert->Table/Matrix->New`.

After adding it to code, Mathematica wrote a remark: "Assuming a matrix | Use a list of lists instead".

Value is already looks as list of lists. Clicking "list of lists" does not change anything visible.

[image]

Comment: In Mathematica, a matrix *is* just a list of lists, so don't worry. This just means that the suggestions bar offers suggestions for matrices. If you clicked on "list of lists", you'd see different suggestions.

Comment: strictly, a matrix must be 2d with equal length sub lists. functions such as linearsolve will only take proper matrices.

Answer (score 4):

The suggestions bar tries to offer a useful set of follow-up operations based upon the type of a result.  In the case at hand, the result is a list of lists.  But it so happens that all of the sublists are the same length, which happens to be the representation of a matrix in *Mathematica*.  So the suggestions bar has guessed that the user has a matrix in mind and has offered follow-up operations that make sense for matrices.

However, it also realizes that it may have guessed in error.  The user might be thinking about a simple list that, by sheer coincidence, has sublists of equal length.  Hence the offer to treat the result as a list of lists instead.  If we accept that offer, we are shown operations that make sense for nested lists:

[image: suggestions bar screenshot]

... along with the option to switch back to the matrix operations we were shown in the first place.

The suggestions bar does quite a bit of this inferencing.  The goal is to read the user's mind -- but to give back-up options in case the mind-reading facility picks up the wrong signals ;)